# How to make a custom item renderer in flex 4 without extending the ItemRenderer class?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How to make a custom item renderer in flex 4 without extending the ItemRenderer class?

I need this because I want to use a custom class that is extended in all my components. as this item renderer for me is like a component, i would like to extend that custom class. Thanks ;)

Now im having something like this:

```
imageList.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(ThumbView);
imageList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection([{imageNameString: fileReference.name, imageData: fileReference.data}]);
```

the ThumbView doesn't extend the ItemRenderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For itemRenderers to spark components, implement the [IItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IItemRenderer.html) interface and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! that is right, but now I found that implement IDataRenderer is just enought. But no indexes.. :s